# ASP.NET Caching - Programatically Invalidating Server Cache...confusion on example

Tags: asp.net, caching, httphandler

I'm reading how to programmatically invalidate cached pages on the server in ASP.NET, and the book ("MCTS Self-Paced Traing Kit (Exam 70-515)") says:

> To directly control whether a cached
>   version of a page is used or whether
>   the page is dynamically generated,
>   response to the ValidateCacheOutput
>   event and set a valid value for the
>   HttpValidationStatus attribute.

The code segments look like the following:

```
public static void ValidateCacheOutput(HttpContext context, Object data,
        ref HttpValidationStatus status)
{
    if (context.Request.QueryString["Status"] != null)
    {
        string pageStatus = context.Request.QueryString["Status"];

        if (pageStatus == "invalid")
            status = HttpValidationStatus.Invalid;
        else if (pageStatus == "ignore")
            status = HttpValidationStatus.IgnoreThisRequest;
        else
            status = HttpValidationStatus.Valid;
    }
    else
        status = HttpValidationStatus.Valid;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.AddValidationCallback(
        new HttpCacheValidateHandler(ValidateCacheOutput),
        null);
}
```

Could someone please explain to me what this code is doing?  Also, the main question I have is that I thought Cached pages were simply returned from the server, but the code below indicates that the page life-cycle is being invoked (Page_Load event); I'm confused because the page life-cycle isn't invoked if a cached page is returned, so how would the code in the Page_Load event even fire?

Note:  Here's the [same example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5e5hdyz.aspx) that the book has

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this question. It is too bad that almost every blog post and article I find about this subject dutifully replicates the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5e5hdyz.aspx) without really explaining how it works.

I don't have a definite answer but I think this works because the page life cycle is invoked at least once. Namely when the page is requested for the first time and thus isn't cached yet.
During that first request the Page_Load is called and the `HttpCacheValidateHandler` is registered with the Cache object. During all subsequent request for that page, the Cache object is able to call your `ValidateCacheOutput()` method. And because this method is `static` the page life-cycle doesn't have to be invoked.

I hope that someone who knows more about this can comment on it but in my opinion this also implies the following:

1. In the given example the `HttpCacheValidateHandler` doesn't need to be a static method of the page because it doesn't use any properties of the `Page` object. It can be a static method on any other object you like.
2. The `ValidateCacheOutput()` method will probably be called for every page request, not just for the page which is (ab)used to call `Response.Cache.AddValidationCallback()`. Maybe i'm missing something obvious but I don't see how the Cache "knows" which `HttpCacheValidateHandler` belongs to which page.

Comment: About 2, wouldn't that mean that if you return HttpValidationStatus.Invalid from ValidateCacheOutput, the Page_Load would be fired again and the validation callback be added a second time?

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that typically cached pages are just returned frm the server but this changes when you use AddValidationCallback. In this case, ASP.NET will call this method to determine whether to returned a cached copy or not. This method should therefore be very light or you will negate the effect of caching.

The code you have listed just checks the querystring for a Status variable and uses the value of this to determine whether to either (1) pull the page from the cache, (2) clear the cached page, re-render it and cache it or (3) just ignore the cache and re-render the page.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpvalidationstatus.aspx for the status options.